# Tesseract not recognizing the special characters in a image

Tags: ios, string, tesseract, ascii-art

I have been using Tesseract OCR to recognize text in the image. It's working fine with images having the plain text like "**HI, This is Ramakrishna**". But it not recognizing correctly When my image has the special characters(including space) like in the below images

[image]

[image]

And here my code

```
var tesseract = G8Tesseract(language: "eng")
tesseract.pageSegmentationMode = .Auto
tesseract.engineMode  = .TesseractOnly
let value = "~`!@#$%^&*()-=_+[] {};:<>,'.?/\\\"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
tesseract.setVariableValue(value, forKey: "tessedit_char_whitelist")
tesseract.charWhitelist = value
tesseract.image = UIImage(named: "Sample3")!
tesseract.recognize()
print(tesseract.recognizedText)
```

And the result I'm getting is like this

```
 l_ _I
 IHHIHIHIHIH
 / \vvww \
```

How can I make it recognize the special characters also as they are in the images?

Comment: Just a hunch: OCR are heavily based on statistics, and surely have much higher probability assigned to frequently used characters. So, combinations like |-| might be recognized as H. Another problem might be the scaling - First step of OCRing is normally recognizing the size of the letters. Lack of real text could make the program be confused as to how many of the above lines constitute one character. If you can include some reference words on each line, that might help (or define/limit the character size)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now I understand that how it will work.